# Filter log messages by time (frequency)?

Tags: java, logging, filtering, logback

I have some procedures where log events occur very often. Are there any means to filter events from that class by frequency? For example, no more than 1 message in second or something?

I focus on logback.

Comment: This is a custom behavior for logging, you have several alternatives: 1-custom logger for the category you want to reduce logging (since this is not a common use scenario), 2-reduce the level of logging (ie DEBUG instead of INFO for logs repeating too many times), 3- AOP for the log event, adding the logic to ignore repeating logs in the corresponding category. I would go with 2, just log what is important and not very repetitive. you can send these debug logs to a separate file, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the logback filters 
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html

Specifically, have a look at DuplicateMessageFilter. If that is not enough, you can try to extend it and implement something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using a [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
private Queue<LogMessage> messages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<LogMessage>();
private int messagesPerSecond = 3;
private ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

private Runnable scheduledTask = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        LogMessage message = messages.poll();
        if(message != null) printMessage(message);
    }
};

// ...

ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(, 0, 1000/messagesPerSecond, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

and instead of printing the message directly, you put it into the queue and the scheduled task will handle it.